# AlchemyCMS: Get all elements from a subtree

Tags: alchemy-cms

There is probably an easy way to do this, but I couldn't find anything about it in the [guides](https://guides.alchemy-cms.com/edge/index.html):

I have a page called "Logic" and this page has 20 subpages.

Now, in the page "Logic", I'd like to render the title of all those 20 subpages. How can I do that?

Example:

```
@all-pages-under-logic.each do |page|
 = page.title
end
```

First, I thought that the method [render_subnavigation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/magiclabs/alchemy_cms/Alchemy/PagesHelper#render_subnavigation-instance_method) might be useful. But it seems that it only returns elements, that are visible in the navigation.

Answer (score 2):

Answered by tvdeyen from the alchemy cms slack channel:

```
@children = Alchemy::Page.find_by(page_layout: 'logic').children
titles = @children.pluck(:title)
```